# why this javascript decorate function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, decorator

I am looking at decorate function. For example, decorate function can make sum() function to return a double sum. But the following code doesn't work as desired, I changed the 'f' to 'sum', please see comment on relevant line, why I cannot change this?

```
<script>
function doublingDecorator(f) {        

  return function() {

    return 2*sum.apply(this, arguments); // the original code is: return 2*f.apply(this,arguments) I changed to sum, then doesn't work.
  } 
}

// Usage:

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}


var sum =  doublingDecorator(sum);          // sum gets decoration


alert (sum(3,4)); //return 14
</script>
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all, just the line `var sum =  doublingDecorator(sum);` is baffling, you're creating a variable with the same name as your function, overwriting the entire function, and passing the function to the other function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You changed the inner `f.apply` to `sum.apply`.
- You redefine `sum`.

That's why it's breaking. Your change makes it a recursive call that never ends (infinite recursion) because `sum` calls itself over and over again. This is because you reference `sum` inside, which you have also redefined.

Eventually the recursion ends up exceeding the maximum call-stack size.

I recommend leaving `f.apply` as it is. Then your code should work. Another option is to not redefine `sum`. So do this instead:

```
var newSum = doublingOperator(sum);
console.log(newSum(3, 4)); //returns 14
```

Answer (score 3):

`f` in `doublingDecorator` is not used. Instead you reference `sum`, which you also redefine. This causes an infinite loop.

```
function doublingDecorator(f) {        
  return function() {
    return 2*f.apply(this, arguments);
          // ^-- f instead of sum!
  } 
}
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
var sum = doublingDecorator(sum); // note: sum is already declared here, redeclaring is technically wrong.
console.log(sum (3,4)); // 14
```